# Loading data when user goes to next page

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am accesing an api endpoint which atm retrieves > 1000 data objects and returns them to the user.

I don't think this is efficient, as only 30 objects get viewed at once.

Is there a way to load these objects more efficiently (i.e. 30 at a time), especially as I have integrated it with [ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable).

My api allows for this... just need to add the following parameters to URL:

> Paginated results (set page=${pageNumber} and
>   limit=${maxResultsOnPage}) e.g. To limit results to 5 sermons a page
>   and get the 2nd page:

```
 curl --request GET \
    --header 'content-type: application/json' \
    --url 'http://localhost:8080/sermon?limit=5&page=2'
```

**sermon.component.ts**

```
  public getAllSermons() {
    this.sermonSubscription = this.apiService.getAllSermons().subscribe((data: Array<object>) => {
      this.sermons = data;
      this.totalCount = Object.keys(this.sermons).length;
      this.logger.debug(`${data.length} sermons loaded`);
      this.isSermonsLoaded = true;
    });
  }
```

**sermon.component.html**

```
        <ngx-datatable class="material fullscreen" [rows]="sermons" [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
          [selected]="selected" [selectionType]="'single'" [columnMode]="'force'" [headerHeight]="50"
          [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="'auto'" [limit]="30" (select)='onSelect($event)'>
          <ngx-datatable-column name="Date" [width]="80"></ngx-datatable-column>
          <ngx-datatable-column name="Speaker" [width]="200"></ngx-datatable-column>
          <ngx-datatable-column name="Name" [width]="600"></ngx-datatable-column>
        </ngx-datatable>
```

**api.service.ts**

```
  public getAllSermons() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.apiUrl}/sermon?orderBy=date&sortAscending=false`).pipe(map((data: any) => data.data)
    );
  }
```

Comment: `ngx-datatable` supports pagination on its own. Did you check it out?

Answer (score 0):

With ngx-datatable, you can set the input `externalPaging` to true and listen to the event `page`.

Here is an example from the documentation: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/paging/paging-server.component.ts